# RangeSlider in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

**dojox.forms.HorizontalRangeSlider** and **dojox.forms.VerticalRangeSlider** are both defined in */dojox/forms/RangeSlider.js*. What do I need to do to dojoConfig instead of using require statements so the package is only loaded when necessary?

I'm using Dojo 1.8

```
<div style="width: 300px;"
    data-dojo-id="myRangeInputSlider" 
    data-dojo-type="dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider" 
    data-dojo-props="value:[2000,10000], maximum:1000000, discreteValues:20, showButtons:false">
```

It seems [Dojo Ticket #16301](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16301) relates to the same issue - is there a way round the problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Why don't you want to use require statements ? What version of dojo are you using ?

Comment: Thanks - more information above. trying to do it AMD style

Comment: Still no information about the dojo version... if it's dojo 1.8+, there's no reason why this shouldn't work out of the box. But it's still recommended to require the module. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#auto-require

Comment: I put the version number in the question - you missed it :-). Actually your response and your link is quite helpful - What I want is auto require to find dojox/form/RangeSlider.js when I set the data type above, as the RangeSlider.js package contains both horizontal and vertical slider prototypes.

Comment: the "auto require" feature will work, but because both sliders are defined in their own module (dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider.js and dojox/form/VerticalRangeSlider.js). Indeed, the parser expects an exact match between the data-dojo-type attribute and the module to require.

Are you sure to specify "parseOnLoad:true" in your dojoConfig ?

Comment: There is *no* dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider.js in Dojo 1.8 or 1.9 AFAICT. Both horizontal and vertical dijits are declared in dojox/form/RangeSlider.js -because the file is not the same name as the widget, dojo doesn't handle auto-require for Horizontal or Vertical Range sliders.

Comment: @vogomatix you are right (I should not work with trunk...) So, that explains why the "auto require" does not work with the Horizontal/Vertical range sliders: there's no 1-1 match between the type (data-dojo-type="dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider") and a module. And that explains why it works in trunk, where there's a module for each of the range sliders.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way round that issue - it should be possible to "tell" Dojo where to look. BTW thanks for putting the time in to help :-)

Comment: in theory, the 'paths' property of the loader should handle this case, but I tried and it's not fully working in your context for a reason I don't know.
Another workaround would be to define your own module (ex: mypackage/MyHSlider.js) that would require["dojox/form/RangeSlider"] and return dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider (http://pastie.org/8103822). In your markup, set the data-dojo-type to "mypackage/MyHSlider" and it will work.
But IMO, the cleanest solution would be to either require explicitely RangeSlider, or patch locally your dojo distrib to match what's done in trunk.

Comment: Yup, I tried paths and various other dojoConfig settings with only limited success. I'm going with the 'define your own module' approach which seems to be the way forward. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Patrick : I'm strictly limiting to working with Dojo 1.8 in order to be compliant with a clients standards. I used your answer as the basis of a more complete answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, define a module `myapp/dijit/form/HorizontalRangeSlider.js` as:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojox/form/RangeSlider"
], function(declare, lang, on, slider){
    var hrs = dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider;
    var rs = declare( "dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider", hrs, {
        onChange: function(e) {
            // console.log( "HRS Onchange");
        },

        startup: function() {
            // console.log( "HRS Startup");
     }
    });

    return rs;
});
```

Any other alternative ideas or suggestions on how to use `dojoConfig` to auto require properly would be appreciated!